# Cakephp and Javascript: How to get value from find('list')

Tags: javascript, cakephp

I have controller Book use find('list')

```
<?php 
     $this->set('books',$this->Book->find('list')); 
?>
```

I use pr() to show result. [4],[5]... is Book id

```
array{
    [4] => Chapter 1
    [5] => Chapter 2
    [7] => Chapter 3
    [8] => Chapter 4
    [10] => Chapter 5
}
```

I need get this book id. So I use javascript with *onchange* action to get selected book id. But, result is ***undefined***. It cannot get select box Book id values. So, please teach me how to get it. Thanks

Code view.ctp

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Book',array('onchange'=>"alert(this.value)")) ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('List',array('options'=>$books,'type'=>'select')) ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end() ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo $this->Form->create('Book',array('onchange' =>    "alert(document.getElementById('BookList').value)"));
echo $this->Form->input('List',array('options' => $books, 'id' => 'BookList', 'type' => 'select'));
echo $this->Form->end();
```

if you are using jquery:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Book',array('onchange' => "alert($('#BookList').val())"));
```